# Is the title of Borat movie grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

**Borat: Cultural Learnings of America for Make Benefit Glorious Nation of Kazakhstan**, is this title grammatically correct ? It seems wrong to me but I was wondering if there was any such kind of use of "make benefit" that I didn't know.
Let me know if this question doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't. That's part of the joke. A grammatically correct version would be something like "Learning about the culture of America in order to benefit the glorious nation of Kazakhstan", which is nowhere near as funny.